# Updating database Model view controller rails 4 method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, crud

I want to call a method that updates an attribute when saved.

Here is my index.html.erb

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
<div>
    <strong><%= user.email %></strong> 
</div>
 <% if can? :update, User %>
 <%= link_to 'Make Author', User, method: :add_roles %>
 <% end %>
```

**Below is my user_controller.rb**

```
  def add_roles
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    user.author = true
    user.save!
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

It doesn't update the attribute though. I think it is because I am not properly attaching it to the correct user. I want to current_user to update another user.

Comment: ```method: :add_roles``` is telling a javascript code(from jquery-ujs) to make an HTTP request with that method verb(which does not exist). The method should be PATCH(```:patch```) both in the ```link_to ..``` and in your routes.rb(e.g ```patch 'users/:id/add_roles' => 'users#add_roles'```)

Comment: So instead it would be    <%= link_to 'Make Author', User, method: :add_roles %> ? What do I add to the routes.rb?

Comment: In the view
```<%= link_to 'Make Author', "/users/#{user.id}/add_roles", method: :patch %>```
In the routes.rb
```patch '/users/:id/add_roles' => 'user#add_roles'```.

Comment: Ok when I do that I get this error 'uninitialized constant UsersController'

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simple, first do what avlazarov said in his comment:

> In the view <%= link_to 'Make Author', "/users/#{user.id}/add_roles",
>   method: :patch %> In the routes.rb patch '/users/:id/add_roles' =>
>   'user#add_roles'

Or something simpler, in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  patch :add_roles, on: :member
end
```

then in view:

```
<%= link_to 'Make author', add_roles_users_path(user) %>
```

Then rename user_controller.rb placed in app/controllers to users_controller.rb and make sure the class name is UsersController.